# How to serialize ActivatedRoute to string in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build breadcrumb to display in my "shell" component (one with `<router-outlet>`). I'm injecting Angular's `Router` service, and by traversing it from `routerState.root` down through its `firstChild` (or `children[0]`) property until null, building the (linked) list of components comprising currently displayed route. The result is a linked list of `ActivatedRoute` objects. As I'm attaching custom data to each defined route (e.g. title), that I can get (via `ActivatedRoute.data` member) at runtime, so I can display names of items in breadcrumbs.

But the problem is with links (urls). `ActivatedRoute` has all the info about particular route in chain, but I couldn't find a way to serialize it to single string value, to use as a link in breadcrumb. I could manually parse it of course, but this is waaaay too much work for something so essential. `ActivatedRoute` has urls (itself split in segments), query params, matrix params, etc. all in different properties (some of them even Observables, to unnecessarily complicate things)... but no single string property that gives complete urls (with params and everything).

Incidentally, the `Router` service has `serializeUrl()` member that takes parameter of type `UrlTree`, and converts it to string. Maybe there is some method that converts `ActivatedRoute` into `UrlTree`, so that I could then use `Router.serializeUrl()`?..

Simply: **How can I get serialized string out of `ActivatedRoute` (or `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`) object? (Without writing the whole parsing logic myself obviously).**

It seems so essential thing to need, as ActivatedRoute is essentially parsed representation of string url (if I'm understanding this whole concept correctly)... and `Router` even has helper method to stringify `UrlTree` object (which is never explained how to retrieve in the first place)...

Answer (score 9):

`router.createUrlTree` can receive an `ActivatedRoute`.

```
@Component({
  selector: "foo"
})
class Foo {
  constructor(router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    const urlTree = router.createUrlTree(["."], { relativeTo: route });
    console.log(router.serializeUrl(urlTree));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try expect this:

```
this.route.children[0].url.value
```

It should be Array containind UrlSegmen object with field path. 
One UrlSegment = one route path